# Pivot_longer on all columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I am using pivot_longer from tidyr to transform a data frame from wide to long. I wish to use all the columns and maintain rownames in a column as well. The earlier melt function works perfect on this call

```
w1 <- reshape2::melt(w)
head(w1)
'data.frame':   900 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Var1 : Factor w/ 30 levels "muscle system process",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Var2 : Factor w/ 30 levels "muscle system process",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

But pivot_longer doesnt

```
w %>% pivot_longer()

Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 23):

Obviously some data would be helpful, but your problem lies in the fact that you are using `pivot_longer()` on an object of class `matrix` and not `data.frame`

```
library(tidyr)

# your error
mycars <- as.matrix(mtcars)
pivot_longer(mycars)
```

```
Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class
  "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

`pivot_longer()` will work on a data frame

```
> class(mycars)
[1] "matrix" "array" 
> class(mtcars)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Remember to specify the `cols` argument, this was not required in `reshape2::melt()` (more info in the documentation). You want all the columns so `cols = everything()`:

```
pivot_longer(mtcars, cols = everything())
```

(Disclaimer: Of course, `mtcars` is not the best dataset to convert to long format)

Comment: This is great! one more thing: how can we keep both rownames  and colnames in the pivot data frame?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) to find out more about column names in the longer data frame (especially the `names_to` and `values_to` arguments). Have a look at [this](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#rownames) to find out why rownames aren't generally supported by `tidyverse`

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply @kmacierzanka. Your answer partly helped me. I have updated my post to clarify on my goals. Cheers!

Comment: It's very hard to help without seeing your initial data, try `dput(head(w))` so we can see your starting point. Also, write out an exact expected output.